# Getting weird ambiguous column error message in where clause when accessing database

Tags: 7, database

I am getting an error that one of the columns I am accessing is ambiguous in my where clause. While I understand what that message means, I believe that my code is set up correctly to avoid such a message. Here is my query:

```
$form_query = db_select('form_permissions', 'perm');
$form_query->join('submission_form', 'sf', 'sf.stage=perm.stage and sf.form_instance = perm.form_instance');
$form_result = $form_query
  ->fields('perm', array('form_instance', 'role'))
  ->fields('sf', array('submitted'))
  ->condition('perm.process', $submission->process)
  ->condition('perm.stage', $submission->current_stage)   <--- complains about this condition
  ->condition('perm.can_create', 1)
  ->execute();
```

I specify which table column I am interested in so why is this an issue? Is this a bug in Drupal 7?

Thanks